# Clarification about a notation $O_{\epsilon}(c^{1/2+ \epsilon})$

Tags: modular-forms

I've been reading the book "Some applications of modular forms" by Peter Sarnak. On page 25, where he is trying to find a bound for the Fourier coefficients of the Poincaré series the notation  $O_{\epsilon}(c^{1/2+ \epsilon})$ comes up. I am familiar with the "Big O" notation but I haven't had any luck about finding this one online.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is probably meant (although we’d need to see the text ot be sure) is that the unknown quantity $X$ satisfies, for every $\epsilon$, an inequality $|X| \leq Ac^{1/2+\epsilon}$, where $A$ is a positive number that depends on $\epsilon$ and no other variable stuff.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you very much!